# How to get xml output of text for stanford corenlp

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I've been reading the API and the documentation trying to find an answer, but haven't gotten close to solving the problem.

I want to take a bunch of sentences and get the output as XML for all the sentences:

```
      <token id="1"> 
        <word>That</word> 
        <lemma>that</lemma> 
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>0</CharacterOffsetBegin> 
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>4</CharacterOffsetEnd> 
        <POS>DT</POS> 
        <NER>O</NER> 
      </token>
```

I only managed to figure out how to get the tree parsed, but that's not helpful to the thing I want to build. Anyways, here's the code I'm using right now:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

// read some text in the text variable
String text = "We won the game."; // Add your text here!

// create an empty Annotation just with the given text
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

// run all Annotators on this text
pipeline.annotate(document);

// these are all the sentences in this document
// a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {

  // this is the parse tree of the current sentence
  Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);

  // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
  SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
}
```

I'm using the code in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

A bit easier using built-in xmlPrint:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Annotation document = new Annotation("Four score and seven years ago.");
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("./target/", "nlp.xml"));
    pipeline.xmlPrint(document, os);
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me about 4 hours, but I finally found some source code that helped. Here's the updated code:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

// read some text in the text variable
String text = "We won the game."; // Add your text here!

// create an empty Annotation just with the given text
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

// run all Annotators on this text
pipeline.annotate(document);

Document xmldoc = XMLOutputter.annotationToDoc(document, pipeline);
// below is a tweaked version of XMLOutputter.writeXml()
ByteArrayOutputStream sw = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Serializer ser = new Serializer(sw);
    ser.setIndent(0);
    ser.setLineSeparator("\n"); // gonna kill this in a moment
    ser.write(xmldoc);
    ser.flush();
String xmlstr = sw.toString();
xmlstr = xmlstr.replace("\n", "");
System.out.println(xmlstr);
```

Hopefully this helps someone out in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tiffan Meloney.

It was very helpful, i also found another way, based in your example:

```
Document doc = XMLOutputter.annotationToDoc(annotation, pipeline);
System.out.println( doc.toXML() );
```

I also hope this help someone else